# How do I create my own GPU accelerated graphics API in C#?

Tags: c#, xna, graphics-programming, hardware-acceleration

I am creating 2D game engine in C# and I need some graphic API, so that user can draw sprites or convex vector shapes. I tried to use [GDI+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Device_Interface) for it. But I discovered that GDI+ is not GPU accelerated and it is too slow. [XNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA) (a toolset for game developers form Microsoft) and it is GPU accelerated.

So I made a performance comparison between XNA and GDI+. XNA draws 2048x2048 px sprite in ~0.05 ms in GDI+ it takes about 400-500 ms. How to start? How to make my own graphic API (like DirectX/OpenGL).

Comment: You can make your own graphics API if you find an open source graphics hardware or you design your own. Otherwise, you can convince AMD and Nvidia to support your new API. </sarcasm>. The best thing you can do is not doing that. Seriously. Instead, consider working with either OpenGL and/or DirectX and build a wrapper around it. Even better, use a wrapper that already exists and don't reinvent the wheel. XNA uses DirectX for example. It is just a wrapper around it.

Comment: *Why* would you even want to do that? There's no reason whatsoever to reinvent the wheel. Also the question *"what is the difference between DirectX and OpenGL which one is better?"* is both too broad and opinion based. Both have their pros and cons and you need to evaluate for yourself which one suits our requirements (also you forgot to include Vulkan)

Comment: If you are look at using DirectX from a managed languish then you should use SharpDX as its almost 1:1 with native DirectX and if you use the updated tool kit you get a very good sprite batch system that works just like XNA's

Comment: So why do you not want to use XNA? (Btw XNA is no longer supported so you would probably want to use MonoGame instead)

Comment: 500ms to draw a 2k by 2k sprite? That seems very unlikely.

Comment: @DavidLively Between every screen update it takes 1000 ms / 60 Hz (screen refresh rate) ≈ 16 ms. And what if I need to draw colorful background on 1920x1080 px monitor it takes about 20 game frames.

Comment: @Ovidzikas Yes, which is still far less than 500ms. If your desktop was only running at 2Hz, you'd have noticed long before now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Practically speaking, you can't.

The parts of D3D or OpenGL that provide the *hardware acceleration* are the drivers that talk to the underlying GPU hardware. For the most part these are provided by the manufacturers of the GPU hardware itself, because they know all of the ins and outs of how that hardware works.

A big portion of "creating your own" hardware-accelerated graphics API would be writing these drivers, which is a monumental undertaking, especially when you don't have all the proprietary information about the hardware. You can take a look at some of the [open-source nVidia drivers](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/) to get an idea of the scope here.

And to write such a driver in C#, instead of C, would require an operating system that would accept such a driver, one that had a CLR runtime that operated in kernel mode. While such operating systems exist, they are largely toys or research projects.

Answer (score 2):

*How to create your own GPU accelerated graphics API in C#?*

Short answer: You don't.

---

Long answer:

you said you tried GDI+ and XNA and you want do something like DirectX or OpenGL... well, why have you not tried a low level DirectX wrapper such as <strike>[SlimDX](https://slimdx.org/)</strike> [SharpDX](http://sharpdx.org/) or a low level OpenGL wrapper for C# such as [OpenTK](https://opentk.github.io/)?

Mono is building a [Vulkan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulkan_(API)) [wrapper for .NET](https://github.com/mono/VulkanSharp) - do you wanna try and help them?

Note: DirectX is not equivalent to OpenGL, as DirectX includes libraries not related to graphics. You can find comparisons and debates of which is better *elsewhere*.

Some game engines would wrap those and hide them behind their own API, in such way that the game developer can switch from one to the other without having to change all the code. If that is what you want to do, then you start by learning to use those and adding an absctraction layer ontop.

On the other hand, if what you want is to compete with DirectX and OpenGL... well, you could try inventing a graphics API, but then no hardware would support it... so you get no hardware accelaration (if get it to work). You could then decide to speak to the standards to support the wider range of hardware possible, turns out that by doing that you are using their API. So, no, you don't make your own GPU accelerated graphics API unless you have some control over the hardware (or you control a huge share of the operating system market to pressure those who do).

Comment: SlimDX is very old and out of date, sharpDX is your best bet for  managed DirectX.

Comment: @JustinWilliamStanleyBryant I wouldn't know, its been a while since I used any DirectX related stuff. Added SharpDX link to the answer.